Unable to append text to a .txt file on my android device using kotlin
My kotlin script has a function that runs many times per second to collect sensor data from my android device. The script is meant to write the data into a .txt file in a directory with rel path /Documents/Data
I am using the following function to write data into a file data.txt.
Unfortunately my script just makes the file (if it doesn't exist) and doesn't write anything into it. If the file does exist, it makes no changes to the file.
I do call the function multiple times.
How can I fix this? I'm not sure what's causing this issue.
fun saveData(context: Context, fileName: String, text: String) {
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

    // Query for the existing file
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME} = ?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(fileName)

    val cursor = contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )

    if (cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {
        // File exists, get the URI
        val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID))
        val uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external").buildUpon().appendPath(id.toString()).build()

        // Open the file for appending
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wa")?.use { outputStream ->
            OutputStreamWriter(outputStream).apply {
                append(text)
                flush()
            }
        } ?: run {
            println("Failed to open the file for appending.")
        }
    } else {
        // File does not exist, create a new one
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
            put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents/Data/")
        }

        val uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)
        uri?.let {
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)?.use { outputStream ->
                outputStream.write(text.toByteArray())
            }
        } ?: run {
            println("Failed to create the file.")
        }
    }

    cursor?.close()
}    


works fine when I tested it
